# GET http://localhost:4200/assets/pdf.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular

hi can anyine solve my issue
while using ngx extended pdf viewer in my angular version 10 it works file,but while using along with my angular material it shows an error
my html page

error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66BJW.png)

Comment: Before you post, search the site to make sure your question hasn’t been answered
1.Summarize the problem
2.Provide details and any research
3.When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried

Comment: @aisha please provide your code so that we can see

Answer (score 4):

Please check your `angular.json`. The error message indicates you don't copy the `pdf.min.js` file from the `node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer` folder to the assets folder of your application. You can check this by running `ng build` and checking the content of your `dist` folder.

I've compiled the steps to get your application up and running here: https://pdfviewer.net/getting-started. BTW, that's also an Angular Material application running on Angular 10.

**Update June 21, 2022:**
In the meantime, I've implemented an Angular schematics to set up the PDF viewer in your application. `ng add ngx-extended-pdf-viewer` usually saves you a lot of headaches. If that doesn't work out-of-the -box, create a new project (`ng new demo`), followed by `cd demo` and `ng add ngx-extended-pdf-viewer`. Now you've got a project with a running demo component using the PDF viewer, which is a good starting point to compare the setup to your project.